# How can I create a date field in tableau, If I have only a list of years in the data set as string data type. I am working CO2 raw dataset

Tags: excel, visualization, tableau-api

I am working with CO2 raw data set for tableau visualization. I have to use date field for visualization. But in the given data set there is no date field only years as the column name, each year column contains CO2 emission of each countries in the corresponding years.
how do I create a date field to do the visualization?

Problems are;

1. Using the CO2 Per Capita RAW DATA table, for the date range April 9, 1987 to July 18, 2007, determine. India’s rank in terms of CO2 emissions and the CO2 emission value using a Bar Chart.
2. Using the Year over Year Growth, how many years have negative growth in terms of CO2 value? You can use any kind of chart

I tried to get date using parameters but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Dates have three parts - a month, day and year. If you only know part of the info, you have to make a choice how to supply the missing component. A typical choice is to choose the first day or first month in the absence of more info.

Given that, you can use the MAKE_DATE(), DATE_PARSE() or the DATE() function to create a date from whatever strings and/or integers you have.

Similarly, Datetime values also add hour, minutes and seconds.